# How to export drupal database (version 6)?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I am trying to migrate a Drupal site for my client. But I don't know how to export the database. Can I export it from admin login?

I don't think I have phpadmin login address. Unless it can be found from the php files. Cheers.

Comment: This might be better suited to another stack exchange site. For example there is an answer here... http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/5452

Comment: Do it manualy using PHPmyadmin interface. Download the .sql file.
On new server, do a clean install using that Drupal pack and then import the .sql file you have exported earlier!

Comment: Use back up & migrate module as suggested in one of the answers. You can Login to admin, take back up of DB or restore an existing back up using this module.

Answer (score 2):

Use Drupal's [backup and migrate module](https://drupal.org/project/backup_migrate).